# When new items are added, the first existing items are not animated using framer motion

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

When there are only two items initially, clicking Add will add new item (3rd item). The 2nd item will go below and show a heading. Going below is not animated.

In the same way, when there are 3 items and clicked Delete, the last movement is not animated.

Demo with full source can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-dream-229d2y?file=/src/App.tsx

This is the source code for archive purposes:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { AnimatePresence, AnimateSharedLayout, motion } from "framer-motion";

function SomeItem() {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        border: "1px solid blue",
        padding: "12px",
        height: 60,
        width: "100%",
        margin: "12px"
      }}
    >
      {new Date().toISOString()}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<typeof SomeItem[]>([SomeItem, SomeItem]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          setItems((prev) => prev.filter((_p, i) => i !== prev.length - 1))
        }
      >
        Delete
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setItems((prev) => [...prev, SomeItem])}>
        Add
      </button>

      <section>
        <h3>What&apos;s not working?</h3>
        <p>
          When there are only two items initially, clicking Add will add new
          item (3rd item). The 2nd item will go below and show a heading. Going
          below is not animated.
        </p>
        <p>
          In the same way, when there are 3 items and clicked Delete, the last
          movement is not animated.
        </p>
      </section>

      <AnimateSharedLayout>
        <ul style={{ listStyle: "none", margin: 0, padding: 0 }}>
          <AnimatePresence initial>
            {items.map((Item, i) => (
              <motion.li
                key={i}
                layout
                animate={{ transition: { damping: 1000 }, y: 0 }}
                exit={{ opacity: 0, transition: { damping: 1000 }, y: "-110%" }}
                initial={{ y: "-110%" }}
              >
                {i !== 0 && items.length > 2 && (
                  <motion.h3
                    animate={{ transition: { damping: 0 }, x: 0 }}
                    exit={{ x: "-100%" }}
                    initial={{ x: "-100%" }}
                  >
                    Item {i}
                  </motion.h3>
                )}
                <Item />
              </motion.li>
            ))}
          </AnimatePresence>
        </ul>
      </AnimateSharedLayout>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Demo of the not working animation]

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be at this conditional `i !== 0 && items.length > 2`, when the `items.length` is greater than two it's rendering two headers at same time because you specified to only render the header after the item of **index 0**, thus when you delete the item it's also deleting the two headers at same time and just animating the last one. To fix it you can change the conditional to `i !== 0 && items.length > 1`, this way it will render item 1, item 2 and so on. [see the working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-sky-0oeg9c?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately the suggested change is part of the requirement. Headers can only be visible if there are 3 or more items. In any case, the headers are both animated when entering but only 1 is animated when exiting. That's what's puzzling.